# How to get an activeted lineEdit or label in pyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit

I'm trying to get a lineEdit that have a cursor in it when a button is clicked. For example: I run application, put a cursor in one lineEdit, and when clicking a button - some text should be set in chosen lineEdit.

I've tried with keyboardGrabber, but it returns button =None.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class Mainwindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("window")
        self.lineEdit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setText('#1')
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 200, 100))
        self.gridLayout =  QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit3, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.function)

    def function(self):
        widget = self.keyboardGrabber()
        widget.setText('some text')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application = Mainwindow()
    application.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it: `void QApplication::focusChanged(QWidget *old, QWidget *now)`

This signal is emitted when the widget that has keyboard focus changed from old to now, i.e., because the user pressed the tab-key, clicked into a widget or changed the active window. Both old and now can be nullptr.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class Mainwindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):  # QMainWindow  QWidget
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        QtWidgets.qApp.focusChanged.connect(self.on_focusChanged)       # +++

        self.setWindowTitle("window")
        self.lineEdit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit1.setFocus()                                       # +

        self.lineEdit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setText('#1')

        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)                               # +
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 200, 100))
        self.gridLayout =  QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit3, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.lineFocus = ...                                             # +++
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.function)

    def function(self):
#        widget = self.keyboardGrabber()
#        widget.setText('some text')
        self.lineFocus.setText('some text')

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QWidget*", "QWidget*")
    def on_focusChanged(self, old, now):                                 # +++
        #print(f"\nold: {old}, now: {now}")
        self.lineFocus = old 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = Mainwindow()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]